# Using Guice for Dependency Injection with GAE Basic Scaling Instance

Tags: google-app-engine, guice

I have an application running on GAE (Basic Scaling) which uses Guice for dependency injection.

Guice Listener

```
public class GuiceListener extends GuiceServletContextListener {
private ServletContext servletContext = null;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    servletContext = servletContextEvent.getServletContext();
    super.contextInitialized(servletContextEvent);
}   

/**
 * Function to create Guice Injector 
 */
@Override
protected Injector getInjector() {    
    return Guice.createInjector(
            new GuiceServletModule(),        
            new ServiceInjectionModule()
            );
}
}
```

Guice Servlet Module

```
public class GuiceServletModule extends GuiceSystemServiceServletModule {
@Override
protected void configureServlets() {        
    super.configureServlets();
    Logger.info("Guice configure servelet");
    filter("/*").through(NamespaceFilterCustom.class);

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(PackagesResourceConfig.PROPERTY_PACKAGES, "com.my.service.endpoint");
    params.put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", "true");
    //you can create your own filters to handle request and response differently
    params.put(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS, GZIPContentEncodingFilter.class.getName());
    params.put(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_RESPONSE_FILTERS, GZIPContentEncodingFilter.class.getName());
    serve("/*").with(GuiceContainer.class, params);             
}
}
```

Service Injection Module

```
public class ServiceInjectionModule extends AbstractModule {
@Override
protected void configure() {
bind(Service.class).to(ServiceImpl.class);
}
}
```

My endpoint class expects "Service" object to be injected. The application runs fine when used with GAE Auto Scaling. However the "Service" object is not getting injected when the application runs on GAE Basic Scaling. **Null pointer exception** is thrown when "Service" is accessed.